# Why does the Finder.app accept incoming network connections?

Tags: macos, firewall

When looking at my OSX firewall settings, I see that the finder.app application is set to accept incoming network connections.

How come that's set to true by default?

Comment: IIRC, it's not set to true by default. You must have allowed it at some point.

Comment: Not enabled for me either.

Comment: Maybe. I hope to remember if I did something like allow the Finder to accept connections, though. Disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so that you can receive AirDrop wireless file transfers.